# Can I let my website down usign godaddy

Tags: web

I create a website using web builder in godaddy.
But Now I want that website be unreachable so the status should not be 200.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just call GoDaddy tech support and ask them to do this. They'll walk you through step by step.

One option would be to set your domain to a Parked page. That would still retain your web builder creation to be used at a later time.